# Qt toolbar and menubar

Tags: c++, qt, custom-controls, toolbar, menubar

Why wont this work? Its supposed to work like this: when "File" is clicked, a toolbar (not a menubar) shows right beneath the menubar with different buttons on it that would be found in a "File" menu, and when "Edit" is clicked the "File" toolbar is hidden and the "Edit" toolbar is shown.

```
menubar = new MyMenuBar(this);//this is a menubar with "file" and "edit"
menubar->setGeometry(0,0,1100,30);

ftoolbar = new MyFileToolBar(this); // this is a toolbar with buttons that would be
// found in a "file" menu
ftoolbar->setGeometry(0,30,1100,40);
ftoolbar->hide();

etoolbar = new MyEditToolBar(this); // this is a toolbar with buttons that would be
//found in an "edit" menu
etoolbar->setGeometry(0,30,1100,40);
etoolbar->hide();

//here down does not work
connect(menubar->File, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), ftoolbar, SLOT(show()));
connect(menubar->File, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), ftoolbar, SLOT(hide()));


connect(menubar->Edit, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), etoolbar, SLOT(show()));
connect(menubar->Edit, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), etoolbar, SLOT(hide()));
```

File
[image: File]
 Edit[image: Edit]

Comment: Nevermind! I fixed it but stacko isn't letting me answer my question for some reason... so don't answer. I replaced triggered(QAction*) with aboutToShow()

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a screenshot of a toolbar inside of a menu bar.

Comment: @Sosukodo: Beneath the menu bar (in its normal place). Not inside it.

Comment: It sounds intriguing but I can't wrap my head around it. Do you know of any applications that act like this? I have Windows, Macs, Android and Linux(Mint) devices so anything you can point me to would be great!

Comment: btw those buttons are in a toolbar but it doesn't show up well on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bad assumption about what `triggered(QAction*)` meant.

I replaced

```
connect(menubar->File, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), ftoolbar, SLOT(show()));
connect(menubar->File, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), ftoolbar, SLOT(hide()));


connect(menubar->Edit, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), etoolbar, SLOT(show()));
connect(menubar->Edit, SIGNAL(triggered(QAction*)), etoolbar, SLOT(hide()));
```

with

```
connect(menubar->File, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), ftoolbar, SLOT(show()));
connect(menubar->File, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), ftoolbar, SLOT(hide()));


connect(menubar->Edit, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), etoolbar, SLOT(show()));
connect(menubar->Edit, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), etoolbar, SLOT(hide()));
```